# how to chang jquery ui layout slider cursor

Tags: jquery-layout

I'm using the layout in the link below and I'm trying to change the cursor on the west slider bar (if you dbl click it and it closes and then mouse over it) to be default vs the hand but I can't for the life of me figure out how to change it. Does anyone know?

http://jsfiddle.net/5EECD/375/

This library is huge and I can't find out where to change the cursor for this area. I simply don't know any other way to ask this question.

I defaults are just used in the fiddler but there must be some setting for this cursor I assume.

```
$('body').layout({ applyDefaultStyles: true });
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Well it's not my site it's just the demo site of the library. I'm using this library in a node-webkit app, but I guess I can piece together a fiddler that shows the exact same site layout and ask the same question of how to change the cursor over a certain element.

Comment: I am confused on what you actually want to modify. I am familiar with this stupid library as I have had to do many mods myself, but if you still need an answer to this try to give some clarification on what you actually want done.